# Upgrading to JUnit 5.8.0 in combation with Maven Surefire plugin 3.0.0-M5 gives NoSuchMethodError

Tags: junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

After upgrading JUnit from 5.7.2 to 5.8.0, it seems not to work anymore in combination with the Maven Surefire plugin.
Initially, the following error pops up:

```
[ERROR] Please refer to /some/directory/app/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

After looking at the dump, the following errors are given:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:67)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'some.test.class'] resolution failed
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:46)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:103)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Optional org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class, boolean)'
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.getDisplayNameGenerator(DisplayNameUtils.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.lambda$createDisplayNameSupplierForClass$2(DisplayNameUtils.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.determineDisplayName(DisplayNameUtils.java:88)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.<init>(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:96)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassTestDescriptor.java:51)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.newClassTestDescriptor(ClassSelectorResolver.java:119)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$0(ClassSelectorResolver.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution$DefaultContext.createAndAdd(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:246)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution$DefaultContext.addToParent(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:209)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:134)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:185)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:91)
    ... 16 more
```

Does anyone have the same problem while updating? I'm kind of stuck :(
Updating the Maven Surefire Plugin was the first thing that came to my mind, but it seems we already use the latest version (3.0.0-M5).

Edit 1: As requested, the POM:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <sonarqube-plugin.version>3.2.0</sonarqube-plugin.version>

    <compas.core.version>0.4.0</compas.core.version>
    <jakarta-bind-api.version>2.3.3</jakarta-bind-api.version>
    <jaxb-impl.version>2.3.5</jaxb-impl.version>
    <jakarta-cdi-api.version>2.0.2</jakarta-cdi-api.version>
    <microprofile-config-api.version>2.0</microprofile-config-api.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.32</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <basex.version>9.2.4</basex.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.8.0</junit-jupiter.version>
    <mockito-junit-jupiter.version>3.12.4</mockito-junit-jupiter.version>
    <openpojo.version>0.9.1</openpojo.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch across JUnit modules. Can you show your pom file?

Comment: @johanneslink Added the POM versions!

Comment: It’s only part of the pom. The concrete dependencies can play a role too.

Comment: This is happening to me with surefire 2.22.2 and JUnit 5.8. It was working with JUnit 5.7 and below. So I think the problem is more in the junit side

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and it appears that it was an issue of the version of junit-platform-commons. Setting this to 1.8.0 solved it.

Or just add a single junit dependency to junit-bom  -- this will ensure that the versions of all junit components are consistent, and fix the issue.